# C# MVC5 Routing for both default and Area without adding "Area" in the routeValues

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, area

I am unable to keep both routing rules working using
`Url.Action("action", "Controller")` without adding `new { Area = "" }` in the link.

Is this possible?
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default area - Avoiding \`, new {area = ""}\` on each link on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270861/set-default-area-avoiding-new-area-on-each-link-on-the-site)

Comment: unavoidable? I am sure there is a better way to not doing this. Thank you @RahulSharma

Answer (score 0):

-> Yes, It is possible.We can using area in the route values wen generating URLs using 'Url.Action'

-> Define Default Route in your RouteConfig.cs file :-

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

-> Define Area-specific Routes :- Define routes for each area in the AreaRegistration class for the area, for example :-

```
public class MyAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "MyArea";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "MyArea_default",
            url: "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

-> Generate URL without Specifiying Area :- Now, when you use Url.Action to generate URLs for controller/action within the default area.and this will generate URL :- /Home/Index

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
```

-> Generate URL for Actio  in area :- To generate Ul for action within area that time specify the area name.and URL :- /MyArea/SomeController/Index

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeController", new { area = "MyArea" })">Some Action</a>
```

-> follow this code, you can maintain routing for both default and area-specific controllers/actions without need to specify the area explicitly when generating URLs for default controllers/actions.